# Case Page Layouts - Insufficient priviliges

Tags: case, page-layout

When trying to open any of the 8 Case Page Layouts in sandbox I suddenly get the error 'Insufficient Privileges'.

I've checked:

- I still have access to page layouts on other objects (e.g. Opportunities, Accounts)
- My profile (System Administrator) has full access to the Case Object
- 'Enhanced Page Layout Editor' is enabled

Does anyone have an idea what could be the issue? I only have this issue in one sandbox (not in production).

Comment: Can you confirm if you have any managed package field/relatedlist on the page layout?

Comment: I've encountered this issue before I believe - in my case it was due to Page Layout corruption from a bad VS Code deployment I think? Check and see if you can open the Page Layouts from Salesforce Classic or not, it's been a while since this happened to me but I believe I was able to open them from there.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but the problem seems to have resolved itself overnight without me changing anything.